# How can i route my signal in my computer?

Tags: audio, signal-routing

Is there any way to route my DAW's signal to skype ? Or skype to daw ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into Soundflower for an Apple solution. There are [tutorials](http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2012/12/16/how-to-use-skype-with-your-daw/) online - that is just one example. Loopback might be a newer solution, and I believe there are [tutorials](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/loopback-podcast-skype-theme-music) for that as well.

JACK and VB-Audio CABLE were already mentioned and are popular for other platforms.

To do fancier things, have a look at some of the Source Elements remote collaboration solutions, like Source-Live for someone to listen to your mix remotely or Source-Connect that allows you to overdub remotely with synced DAWs.

Comment: Nice one. I hadn't seen Loopback before - been using Audio Hijack for that type of task, or Rewire of course in an ASIO-type environment... Plogue Bidule being just a tad incomprehensible & Soundflower being more than a little crashy since Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux you can do that using a frontend for Jack such as patchage or QJackConnect. In Windows this isn't possible as far as I know. For OS X I have no idea.

Comment: For windows, this might do it : http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/